# SVG <use> external SVG shows width / height as 0 when it's loading

Tags: html, svg

I'm including an inline SVG on my webpage and inside that SVG I have a `<use>` to another SVG. Due to a timing bug where sometimes that use-svg has a wrong rotation what I noticed is that the `<use>` has width and height 0 when it's still loading the external SVG, even though I set the width and height on the `<use>` tag.

Having this as 0 causes problems on the rotation and subsequent processing. If I wait for it to load all is well.

(this was tested in Chrome 85.0.4183.121 and Firefox 81.0b2)

I find this strange because if I use an `<image>` to get my external SVG it loads the dimensions I specify when it's loading.

```
<use id="SvgjsUse1044" xlink:href="/images/checkmark.svg#Layer_1" width="8" height="8" x="26" y="-4"></use>
```

**checkmark image:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="8px" height="8px" viewBox="0 0 8 8" enable-background="new 0 0 8 8" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M6.769,0.5L8,1.901L4.307,6.099L3.076,7.5L1.849,6.099L0,4l1.231-1.401l1.845,2.099L6.769,0.5z"/>
</svg>
```

[image: Chrome showing it as 0x0]

I just want it to behave as `<image>` does :) I'm fully aware I can change the logic of the app to wait for it to load but it has a lot of other consequences.

Is there any way to force the browser to understand and follow the width/height of a `<use>` element while loading?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't set `width` and `height` on the `<svg>` parent of the `<use>` element? That's all the matters to the document flow, not the dimensions of any internal elements within the SVG.

Comment: This is a big SVG document that is much bigger than the `<use>` element that is only a small part of it. Parent already has the correct width and height defined. I tried encapsulating the use element with a svg.group before and setting the dimensions there with the same result

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the issue. I'm assuming you're calculating and applying rotations with js, not using CSS or presentation attributes, right?

Comment: @Sean correct, I'm using SVG.JS to simplify but yes, I'm applying matrix transforms to the elements using JS